# Linux kernel module compiling

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to setup MultiPath TCP (mptcp) according to the guide [here](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/DoItYourself)
I understand that I have to download the custom kernel provided there, compile and install it.
My problem is that related guides I found on the net (e.g. [here](http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/), [here](http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/)), they all mention that I have to compile the kernel modules as well (sudo make modules_install).
BUT, in the [mptcp webpage](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/DoItYourself), there is no mention about modules. Do I have to download and compile the "defualt" modules of the kernel of my machine, or I am missing something else here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no conflict in the docs. The "DoItYourself" guide is talking about the specifics of the driver/module involved. 2nd to last line in DIY guide: *Compile, install and reboot your kernel, as it is recommended by your distribution.*

It assumes you already know about what the other pages are talking about.

*A tip:* Find the existing `.config` file for your system/distro. It can save you some work as it will enable the 99% that you *don't* care about but *need* in order to build the mptcp kernel, such as disk drivers, keyboard drivers, etc.

The ubuntu pages talk about where to find this.

After you've done the `git clone ...`, you'll have an `mptcp` directory that has all the kernel sources. Copy *your* `.config` into it.

Then, do all the `make xconfig`, etc. from the ubuntu guide and follow the DIY to enable the mptcp stuff.

Then, you'll need to do `make` and `make modules`, etc., following the instructions for your *distro*

*A tip:* Before you mess with with the `mptcp` kernel source, you may want to practice configuring, building, installing, booting/running a kernel provided by ubuntu. After you can do that successfully, then move on to merging things into the `mptcp` directory.